# Difficulty installing packages from YAML file in conda environment

Tags: python, git, conda, dependency-management

I am trying to recreate a project I found on GitHub by using a YAML file provided in the repository. However, I am facing difficulties in installing the packages listed in the YAML file. I have set up a conda environment and activated it, but the installation process fails, and I receive package not found errors. I suspect that I might be missing something simple since I am relatively new to this process. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

(The link to the GitHub repo is: https://github.com/JohannesBorgqvist/Turing_patterns_bud_scars/blob/main/README.md)

I tried to recreate a project from a Git repository by setting up the required environment using a YAML file. I followed the recommended steps, including creating a new conda environment and activating it. I then attempted to install the packages listed in the YAML file using the conda env create -f environment.yml command.

Initially, the installation failed due to missing packages and unresolved dependencies. I thought this may be because I did not install specific version of Python, numpy and matplotlib. I updated the Python version in the environment and installed the required versions of numpy and matplotlib.

Afterwards, I attempted to run the installation again, but encountered additional package conflicts.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions. Please let me know if there is anything I can provide for you to understand the issue better.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, it's Windows.